# High Performance Multiplication/Evaluation in C#

Tags: c#, performance, matrix, transform, multiplication

Sorry for the vague thread title; hard to succinctly describe my question.

I have a collection of a large number of objects (couple thousand), defined as...

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID;
    public float A;
    public float B;
    public float C;
    public float D;
    public float E;
    public float F;
    public float G;
}
```

If I'm given a multiplier for each one of those float fields, what's the fastest way to find which Item in my large collection has the largest total of those floats multiplied by their multiplier.

For example, I've currently got something like...

```
public Item FindLargest(float aMult, float bMult, float cMult, float dMult, float eMult, float fMult, float gMult)
{
    Item largest = null;
    float largestTotal = 0f;
    foreach(Item item in ItemsCollection)
    {
        float total = item.A * aMult + 
                      item.B * bMult + 
                      item.C * cMult + 
                      item.D * dMult + 
                      item.E * eMult + 
                      item.F * fMult + 
                      item.G * gMult;
        if (total > largestTotal)
        {
            largest = item;
            largestTotal = total;
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

The performance of this is lacking, and so I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to restructure the data in such a way, ahead of time, so that the FindLargest call is much much faster. I've been doing it like this for a while, and performance was fine, with ~40-50 items in the ItemsCollection, but now the design of a different part of my application has changed, and as a byproduct, I need to process much larger set of data (~2000ish instead of ~50ish), so I'm interested in optimizing this further. Thanks for any help anyone can offer!

EDIT: I should have mentioned this to start with: I'm already parallelizing this in that what's calling this is already heavily parallelized. And what's calling this is indeed calling it many times, with many different parameters, very quickly. Every time a value changes in the open document in my app, this needs to be called about a hundred times, and it should feel 'responsive' (already doing all the calculations on multiple background threads, so I don't mean UI lockup).

EDIT 2: See my comments in the accepted answer.

Comment: This is also valid on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are you trying to implement matrix multiplication?

Comment: @Chadd -- Out of curiosity, how long is it taking you right now? And what sort of number ranges are we talking about?

Comment: Wonder if a mathematician would come up with a mathematical solution

Comment: @Chadd: Why do you need to call it around 100 times? Is the expected output different every time?

Comment: Yes, though usually only slightly. Still, the multipliers used are different, each of the 100-200 times. Could say that they're almost always going to be within 10% of each other. Perhaps that's another potential source of optimization... The first time, try them all, but then 2nd-100th times, only try the ones that were within the top 20% of the 1st one's results? Could potentially miss some, but unlikely... I'll look into that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with your function here. I'm taking way less than 0.1 seconds to complete the function with 500,000 items in the collection.

You might want to find a way to optimize the part of the code that calls this function. Using PLINQ at that level should yield better results.

Comment: @Fun Mun Pieng - Yeah, thanks for stating this. I was testing this in LinqPad and its running super fast with like 1,000,000 items. I was starting to think I was doing something wrong!

Comment: +1. The code is pretty much as good as you can get for that particular task - you have to walk all items as there is no way to define ordering between items for such multiplication so any sort of binary search approaches do not work. It is likely called way more times than expected and as result slowing things down.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: who said anything about binary search? what is called more than expected and what slows down?

Comment: @Steven Jeuris:Agree that my comment is not the clearest one :). I mentioned binary search as it is an easiest way to find max IF one can sort items in a some way, but in this case you can't sort in advance as order itself depend on vector of arguments. I think FindLargest is called more often then expected - verifying/fixing this fact could speed code up much more than parallel execution.

Comment: It is indeed being called a lot, and I've verified that it's only being called as much as is _currently_ expected. If I can't find some way to speed this up, I'll resort to some sort of corner cutting; redesigning it such that it needs to be called half as often.

Comment: To clarify, with some actual timings... Each time a value changes in the document my app is editing, some calculations need to be redone for a significant number of objects (commonly about 200-300), and it should feel 'responsive'. Those calculations include the FindLargest call. In order to test the performance, I've got a test method that performs the aforementioned calculations on 20000 objects and returns the time. Currently, that's taking 23.4sec to do, with FindLargest consuming 85% of the time. Previously, when there were only 40-50 items, this was taking 2-3sec.

Comment: OK, I feel silly now. I was suspicious that perhaps my simplification of my issue was somehow over-simplifying it, so I started breaking it down into more concise pieces. I had been passing in the multipliers as one object with all the multipliers on it as properties... Just found that it was recalculating the multipliers every time they were called. Had just glazed over that before, since each one is pretty simple, just a couple simple operations (x*y+z, etc), but just the fact that it's effectively a function call for every multiplier, and those extra operations, really really added up.

Comment: Down to 3.5sec total for that 20000 object test. Gunna mark this answer as correct, since it's what led me to the solution. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Crowdsourcing to the rescue! Don'tcha love it? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

One option is using [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx) to make use of multiple cores.

```
        var result = (from item in ItemsCollection
                      let total = item.A * aMult + 
                                  item.B * bMult + 
                                  item.C * cMult + 
                                  item.D * dMult + 
                                  item.E * eMult + 
                                  item.F * fMult + 
                                  item.G * gMult
                      select new {item, total}).AsParallel().Max(i => i.total);
```

Comment: @Steven - Seems like this would return the largest value, not the largest item.  no?

Comment: @Naraen: You are right, let's see whether I can further linqify it. :)

Comment: Why is this going to be faster? Just wondering. Isn't that going to do the same amount of multiplications anyway?

Comment: @jsoldi: PLINQ should be smart enough to process multiple multiplications in parallel at the same time on different cores.

Comment: @jsoldi - Sure, but now multiple CPU cores are processing the multiplications at the same time, so you're spreading out the workload (instead of doing them one at a time).

Comment: Sorry, just updated the question with this clarification:  I'm already parallelizing this in that what's calling this is already heavily parallelized.

Answer (score 1):

Divide your dataset into 6 contiguous ranges.  Assign each range to a different thread that is launched asynchronously to calculate the largest value.  When all threads are done you'll have 6 different items - one from each range.   Iterate through the 6 to find the one that is the biggest for the whole dataset.

There are further optimizations you could do.

Instead of launching .NET threads yourself, you could simply the coding using Microsoft's PLINQ library

Comment: How would multiple threads help in this scenario? Multiple threads don't magically make a long running process faster! Only as many threads as there are CPU cores would be useful.

Comment: True.  I was assuming multiple CPUs/cores.  Should have stated that explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the question with this clarification:  I'm already parallelizing this in that what's calling this is already heavily parallelized.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx) when doing the multiplication above. You may also consider having a lookup table implemented as a Dictionary holding the Item.ID and it's total. So when the multiplication is done, you can use LINQ to sort and pluck the item with the largest total.  Something like:

`var sortedItems = from item in ItemsTotalsDictionary orderby item.Value descending
                   select item.Key;`

Comment: Sorry, just updated the question with this clarification:  I'm already parallelizing this in that what's calling this is already heavily parallelized.